# Generate QR code from .vcf card / Business card in C# Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I have created a VCard / Business card. I need to create QR code from that Vcard. when user scan then QR code then display option to save that vcard in contact list. I'm able to generate QR code from string but I don't know how to generate QR code of StorageFile / Vcard.

Here is my Code.

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        vcard = e.Parameter as StorageFile;



        IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
            {
                Height = 300,
                Width = 300
            }
        };


        var result2 = vcard;

     //  Result2 contain vcard. but writer.Write()   need string formate.

       // below commented line display error. because result2 is not string 
       // var result = writer.Write(result2);


        var result = writer.Write(result2.ToString());


        var wb = result.ToBitmap() as WriteableBitmap;

        //add to image component
        bar_image.Source = wb;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you find yourself a vCard library for reading in the information, you will have to open the file and decode it yourself.  Some helpful links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Comment: I have created this Vcard by myself. Now I want to generate QR code of this VCard. above link is for generating VCard.

Comment: You can append contact information like name email  etc from Vcard  to one string and pass it to writer function

Comment: yes I did that, QR code generated by this.. but when user scan that QR code all data display in string form. Not as a Vcard.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware can you please help me out for this question ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122189/onesignal-push-notification-clickevent-show-empty-values-windows-phone-8-1-c-sha

Answer (score 0):

Please see this project on GitHub: [QrCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder).

As per the project's [Wiki](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/Advanced-usage---Payload-generators#35-contactdata-mecardvcard), it is possible to generate QR Codes for vCard and several other requirements. For vCards, the QrCoder requires only about 6 lines of code:

-- Copied from the Wiki verbatim:

```
ContactData generator = new ContactData(ContactData.ContactOutputType.VCard3, "John", "Doe");
string payload = generator.ToString();


QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(payload, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
var qrCodeAsBitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```