# How create QR Code with c# that saves information such as a person name with his website and phone number and alot more information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need a C# code in my ASP.NET MVC project to generate a QR Code as my company's logo that this QR Code must have company's information such as company name, website, phone number and much more information about that. This QR Code must have a complex type information and while someone read this with QR Code Reader then it must shows him all of this information and then if this person click on the phone number then this number must be dialed or when he clicked on the URL then he must go to company's website.
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Can you please check this https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

Answer (score 2):

A QR code is simply a container for whatever you want to store. Given your description you want to encode a vCard in the QR code. Most modern devices will be able to decode that information and add it to their contact database. Check this answer [Generate QR code from .vcf card / Business card in C# Windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554769/generate-qr-code-from-vcf-card-business-card-in-c-sharp-windows-phone-8-1) I think this will help you.